# Joining two nodes using SKPhysicsJointFixed in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, sknode, skphysicsjoint

I want to create a fixed connection between two nodes using `SKPhysicsJointFixed`.

Code:

```
let joint = SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint(withBodyA: bodyA, bodyB: bodyB, anchor: anchor)
physicsWorld.add(joint)
```

Before (without joint):

[image]

After (using code above):

[image]

It seems that I’ve calculated everything correct since the line in the middle clearly shows the connection I wanted to create. However there’s now a second line, pointing to the far left and affecting (?) the elements physical behavior.

**How would I connect these two nodes instead / what am I missing here?**